# C# MySQL system not working

Tags: c#, mysql

my code is erroring on the line of

```
mCommand.CommandText = CommandText;
```

The error is as follows:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Program.exe
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If you can help me fix this or link me to a diffrent mysql system with working datarows. I have tried lots of codes and made loads of questions but i cant find any easy working code that works 100% with how i want it to work.

I hope you can help with this problem. All i am trying to do is get the id of the user by their username if you look in the query and to fix the exception of the .CommandText

Full void

```
    public static DataSet ExecuteQuerySet(string CommandText)
    {
        DataSet DataSet = new DataSet();

        mCommand.CommandText = CommandText;

        using (MySqlDataAdapter Adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(mCommand))
        {
            Adapter.Fill(DataSet);
        }

        ResetCommand();
        return DataSet;
    }
```

Form code -

```
        MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection(strMySqlConnectionString);
        DataRow row = Micro_Talk.MySQL.ExecuteQueryRow("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + username + "'");
```

Full mysql class

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Micro_Talk
{
    public static class MySQL
    {
        public static MySqlCommand mCommand;
        public static void ResetCommand()
        {
            mCommand.CommandText = null;
        }
        public static DataSet ExecuteQuerySet(string CommandText)
        {
            DataSet DataSet = new DataSet();

        mCommand.CommandText = CommandText;

        using (MySqlDataAdapter Adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(mCommand))
        {
            Adapter.Fill(DataSet);
        }

        ResetCommand();
        return DataSet;
    }
    public static DataTable ExecuteQueryTable(string CommandText)
    {
        DataSet DataSet = ExecuteQuerySet(CommandText);
        return DataSet.Tables.Count > 0 ? DataSet.Tables[0] : null;
    }
    public static DataRow ExecuteQueryRow(string CommandText)
    {
        DataTable DataTable = ExecuteQueryTable(CommandText);
        return DataTable.Rows.Count > 0 ? DataTable.Rows[0] : null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're never assigning a value to `mCommand`, so it's got a default value of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

As posted in the comments, you need to properly initialize your `mCommand` variable. Try something like this (I modified your query slightly and renamed your connection variable) :

```
// set up your connection
MySqlConnection myConnection= new MySqlConnection(strMySqlConnectionString);

// format your query
string mySelectQuery = string.Format("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{0}' LIMIT 1", username);

// initalize your command properly
MySqlCommand mCommand = new MySqlCommand(mySelectQuery);
mCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

// set your connection 
mCommand.Connection = myConnection;
```

Since you're only looking for one result here, you can use `ExecuteScalar`, as we've  established we only want one result back in the query :

```
// get the result
string result = mCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```